# How to model the relationships among 3 model in Realm?

Tags: swift, realm

I have a very simple relationship among three models now.

```
class Customer: Object {
  dynamic var customer_name = ""
}

class Product: Object {
  dynamic var product_name = ""
}

class Order: Object {
  dynamic var order_id = ""
  dynamic var customer: Customer?
  let products = List<Product>()
}
```

Order need to have the quantity of the one product, so what I am currently doing is

```
class OrderProduct: Object {
  dynamic var order: Order!
  dynamic var product: Product!  
  dynamic var quantity: Int = 0
}
```

I am wondering if there is another way to specify the quantity of one product inside `Order` model instead of creating `OrderProduct`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no other way so far. (In the future though, you might be able to store dictionaries in a Realm, which could allow to solve that differently.)

For now there are the following two possibilities:
The first one as you described in your question, where you store the link to the `Order` on `OrderProduct`:

```
class Order: Object {
  dynamic var order_id = ""
  dynamic var customer: Customer?
  let products = LinkingObjects(fromType: OrderProduct.self, property: "order")
}

class OrderProduct: Object {
  dynamic var order: Order?
  dynamic var product: Product?  
  dynamic var quantity: Int = 0
}
```

Alternatively you can store the relation on the `Order`:

```
class Order: Object {
  dynamic var order_id = ""
  dynamic var customer: Customer?
  let products = List<OrderProduct>()
}

class OrderProduct: Object {
  dynamic var product: Product?  
  dynamic var quantity: Int = 0

  let orders = LinkingObjects(fromType: Order.self, property: "products")
  var order: Order? { return orders.first }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This helps too.